# Laravel 419 (Unkown Status) on request until refresh browser cache

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When logging out from my application I can’t re-login because I get a 419 error. But this is only until I clear the browsers cache. After I reload the page with CTRL + F5 in Chrome (clears cache) I can login without any problems.

I have a Vue.JS frontend and a Laravel backend. They are on the same domain so I decided to put the API routes in the Web file like someone told me in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/bdiyx7/when_to_refresh_a_jwt_token/ekyqhcg?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) comment:

When logging out I perform an action where it makes a post request to my logout route:

```
export function logout() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        axios
            .post('/auth/logout')
            .then(response => {
                res(response.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                rej(err);
            })
    })
}
```

These are my routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'auth:web'], function () {
    Route::get('memory', 'MemoryController@index');
    Route::put('memory/favorite', 'FavoriteController@update');
    Route::get('memory/{id}', 'MemoryController@show');

    Route::post('friend/add', 'FriendshipController@sendRequest');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
});

Route::get('/{any}', 'SinglePageController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

And this is my LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


    use AuthenticatesUsers {
        logout as performLogout;
    }

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/timeline';

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        $this->performLogout($request);
        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

I guess this has someting to do with the way I have setup my Vue and Laravel becuase I am using it as an SPA and it doesn't really refresh the page? Am I right by thinking this or does it have another cause? Because this error only occurs when I log out and try to log in again without refreshing my cache. Do I miss something in my controller?

**Update:**
Seems that I also get this 419 error some times when I click the logout button. The error looks as follows:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/logout 419 (unknown status)

I don't think this has anything to do with not sending a CSRF token with the request because I have this piece of code in my bootstrap.js:

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

    if (token) {
        window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
    } else {
        console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
    }
```

So every request should contain a CSRF header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not reloading page after logout. Your page still has stale `CSRF` token and after logout using it (by trying to login) will produce this error.

Also, your `Auth\LoginController@logout` method tries to redirect to `/`, but you're calling it through API request, so all it does is redirects this request to HTML page.

That should solve this issue:

```php
public function logout(Request $request)
{
  Auth::logout();
  $this->performLogout($request);
  return response()->json(['ok'=>true]); // whatever you want
}
```

```js
export function logout() {
  return axios.post('/auth/logout')
              .then(() => {
                window.location.href = '/';
              })
              .catch(console.error.bind(console));
}
```

Comment: @Baspa Check that you didn't make errors copying it, I use this code in my own project and it should work as expected.